# Assigning to properties inside custom init method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to write custom `init` method for my `UIViewController`. Here is the method itself:

```
- (instancetype)initWithBottomViewController:(UIViewController *)bottomViewController andTopViewController:(UIViewController *)topViewController {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.bottomViewController = bottomViewController;
        self.topViewController = topViewController;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setupBottomViewController {
    /*crashes here because self.bottomViewController appears to be nil*/
    [self addChildViewController:self.bottomViewController];
    [self.bottomViewController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bottomViewController.view];
    [self.bottomViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Console says `-[__NSArrayM insertObject:AtIndex:] object cannot be nil`

I call my `init` function in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    BottomViewController *bottomVC = [[BottomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BottomViewController" bundle:nil];
    TopViewController *topVC = [[TopViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TopViewController" bundle:nil];
    SlideMenuController *slideController = [[SlideMenuController alloc] initWithBottomViewController:bottomVC andTopViewController:topVC];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.rootViewController = slideController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Properties `self.bottomViewController` and `self.topViewController` are declared in `.h` file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *bottomViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *topViewController;
```

The problem is in the assignment to `self.bottomViewController` and `self.topViewController`. `bottomViewController` and `topViewController` aren't `nil`, but `self.bottomViewController` and `self.topViewController` are. I can't figure it out by myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you seeing `nil` values?

Comment: @rmaddy at any point after using `initWithBottomViewController:andTopViewController:` `self.bottomViewController` and `self.topViewController` are `nil`.

Comment: Update your question with a clear example demonstrating your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy edited with crash log

Comment: You still haven't shown how you call `initWithBottomViewController` or `setupBottomViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy should be ok now

Comment: Apple recommends to not use properties in initializers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I implemented empty setter methods for both `self.bottomViewController` and `self.topViewController`.